# YouTube client-side JavaScript API: how to use thumbnails set?

Tags: google-api-js-client

I can't figure out how to use the `gapi.client.youtube.thumbnails.set` client-side JavaScript? All the examples I've found are for node.js and use the following syntax:

```
gapi.client.youtube.thumbnails.set({
  videoId: 'xxxx',
    media: {
      mimeType: "image/jpeg",
      body: fs.createReadStream("some-file.jpg"),
    }
})
```

Obviously the `fs.createReadStream` isn't available in client-side JavaScript. How can I use that API with an image that the user loads via an `<input file="type">` element? I've tried everything I could think of as the value of the `body` media key:

- `fileInputNode`
- `fileInputNode.files`
- `fileInputNode.files[0]`
- `fileInputNode.files[0].arrayBuffer`
- `fileInputNode.files[0].arrayBuffer()`
- `fileInputNode.files[0].stream`
- `fileInputNode.files[0].stream()`
- *base64 encoded data for the image*
- *raw data for the image*

where `fileInputNode` is the HTML element for the file input. In all cases the call to `gapi.client.youtube.thumbnails.set` does not send any data in the request body, and only sets the `videoId` query parameter. So not surprisingly the request fails with "The request does not include the image content."

Does anybody know how to use this method?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with `readAsArrayBuffer` from `FileReader`. Here is a demo:

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('my-input');

function readFileData(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event) => resolve(event.target.result);
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
}

//Event listener for file input
fileInput.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }

  const fileData = await readFileData(file);

  // Call the YouTube API
  try {
    const response = await gapi.client.youtube.thumbnails.set({
      videoId: 'xxxx'
      media: {
        mimeType: file.type,
        body: fileData,
      },
    });

    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; just tried it but it results in the same thing: the request is sent without the image content :(

Comment: Ahh, that's bad :(